# how to create C# web service for mpeg 4 streaming?

Tags: c#, iphone, web-services

I want to create a C# web service for audio steaming (upload n download) to iPhone.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat vague, But I'll assume that you're trying to stream multiple mp4 audio files.
Here are some possible solutions:

- Use an already existing solution: like IceCast or ShoutCast. With that, you'll be able to stream easily. But it's not in "C#".
- You can just serve directly the mp4 via a direct URL to the iPhone, and your service just tell the the URL where to get it. If you're making an iPhone application, you can ask the next song in queue to your service and be able to queue it. (pseudo streaming)
- If you're into making a full fledged streamer, I would suggest you to look at the ".pls" format. It's not a simple task and may require a lot of time to achieve.